# Using local library in Ansible filter_plugin

Tags: python, ansible

I am creating a bunch of filter plugins for Ansible (2.9/2.13) and I would like to have a tools library that can be used by these filter plugins.

I have the directory `filter_plugins` under my playbook directory and in there, I have a bunch of python scripts that provide Ansible with various filters. This works fine.

Now, some of these python scripts have the same functions. Naturally, I would like to move these shared function to a separate library file. So here is what I tried:

- Option 1: have the library file (tools.py) in the directory `filter_plugins`

  - This does not work well. Python can't find the module tools and Ansible gives me this error:

```
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/<REDACTED>/playbook_dir/filter_plugins/tools.py) as it seems to be invalid: module 'ansible.plugins.filter.966997458576792353_tools' has no attribute 'FilterModule'
```

- Option 2: Create a library folder and put the tools.py script there (`import library.tools` or `from library.tools import shared_function`)

  - This doesn't work either (with or without an empty `__init__.py`). Ansible gives me this error:

```
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/<REDACTED>/playbook_dir/filter_plugins/check.py) as it seems to be invalid: No module named 'tools'
```

All the filter scripts look basically the same (some have more filters, some have less):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'filter1': self.filter1,
            'filter2': self.filter2
        }

    def shared_function(data_to_process):
        processed_data = <process_data>
        return processed_data

    def filter1(self, in_data):
        """some code to process in_data to out_data"""
        process_data = <do_some_stuff>
        out_data = shared_function(process_data)
        return out_data

    def filter2(self, in_data):
        """some other code to process in_data to out_data"""
        process_data = <do_some_different_stuff>
        out_data = shared_function(process_data)
        return out_data
```

As `shared_function` is used in more than one filter script, I want to move it out of there to the `tools.py` library

Can anybody help me find the correct way to include local library files in filter plugins for Ansible?

Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you were writing an Ansible *module*, the answer would be to place your shared code inside the [`module_utils`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/module_util.html) directory. Unfortunately, this solution isn't available to plugins such as filters.

Issue [#28770](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28770) has some conversation around this issue, and the recommended solution is to use a playbook-adjacent collection. A [collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/collections_using.html) is a set of resources including plugins, modules, roles, playbooks, etc.

As described [in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/collections_using.html), you can include a collection "adjacent to" (in the same directory as) your playbook:

> You can also keep a collection adjacent to the current playbook, under a collections/ansible_collections/ directory structure.
>
> ```
> playbook.yaml
> ├── collections/
> │   └── ansible_collections/
> │               └── my_namespace/
> │                   └── my_collection/<collection structure lives here>
> ```

I'm going to add a collection `larsks.myplugins` to my local directory, and then create a filter plugin and some shared code. I'll use the following structure:

```
.
├── collections
│   └── ansible_collections
│       └── larsks
│           └── myplugins
│               └── plugins
│                   ├── filter
│                   │   └── myplugin.py
│                   └── module_utils
│                       └── mycommon.py
└── playbook.yaml
```

In `mycommon.py` I have:

```
def mysharedfunction(v):
    return v.upper()
```

In `myplugin.py` I have:

```
from ansible_collections.larsks.myplugins.plugins.module_utils.mycommon import mysharedfunction

class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {'myfilter': mysharedfunction}
```

This allows me to write a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ 'this is a test' | larsks.myplugins.myfilter }}"
```

So there you have a filter plugin importing shared code from another module.